# Double Comparatives

Tags: comparatives

I'm learning English comparatives of Adjectives and Adverbs. I have 2 questions relating to "double comparatives"

Firstly, should I use:

> (1) The better you are at English, the more chances you have to get a job in the international organizations.

or:

> (2) The better at English you are, the more chances to get a job in the international organizations you have.

.

Secondly, when I convert this sentence into a question, if the information to ask is 'chance', should I use:

> (1) What do you have if you are good at English.

or:

> (2) What do you do if you are good at English.

or:

> (3) What do you have to get a job if you are good at English.

Thanks

Comment: "(1) The better you are at English, the more chances you have to get a job in the international organizations." is correct here. As for the second question, it's more appropriate to rephrase it as "What opportunities will you have if you are good at English?"

Comment: The phrases "you are" and "you have" *can* be placed in either location in this case. There may only be a subtle/ insignificant difference in focus if any. As for the second part, I'm afraid it amounts proof-reading. In any case, please try to ask one question per post.

Comment: *The better you are at English, the more chances you have* **of finding a job** OR **of being hired**.

Comment: both chance **of doing sth** and chance **to do sth** are allowed. I looked for 'chance' in Oxford Advanced Learner's dictionary.
btw, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for your first question, both sentences are grammatical. However, it is *usually* a good idea to keep the main idea of a sentence close together. It makes it easier to understand complex or long sentences.

So this version is preferable, because a reader immediately sees the [The better you are, the more chances you have]-construction. (Note that I removed the last *the* as well.)

> The better you are at English, the more chances you have to get a job in international organizations.

As for your second question, the third option is not really a grammatical sentence. If I understand you correctly, the *answer* to the question should be *more chances to get a job*.

Your second question sentence is asking what someone *does*, but you want to know what they *have*. So indeed the first option is the best:

> What do you have if you are good at English?

Note that a question should end in a question mark.

Answer (score 0):

> (1) The better you are at English, the more chances you have to get a
>   job in the international organizations.

is closest to correct although you should not include the second "the"

> The better you are at English, the more chances you have to get a job
>   in international organizations.

or, perhaps better still (as most people only want a job in one organization)

> The better you are at English, the more chances you have to get a job
>   in an international organization.

The  correct phrasing of the question is more difficult as I don't understand what you are trying to ask.
Perhaps you mean:

> Will your chance of getting a job in an international organisation
>   increase if your English is better?

Comment: It appears that the OP's question is about the placement of the phrases -- see my comment at OP.